# Is the source URL available when either a link is clicked or the user redirected to another URL?

Tags: http

When a user clicks a link to an external site from my site, is my sites URL available to the external site? How about if my site redirects the user to the external site?

Also what about the site prior to mine? If the previous URL is available, is the one one step back also available?

Comment: You want to read about [HTTP Referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). (Yes, it's "referer" with bad spelling; that's what happens when a typo enters a standard.) Long story short, the referrer is available if the browser sends it; the web server has no control over the configuration of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **Referer** in Request header: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)

> The Referer request header contains the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed. The Referer header allows servers to identify where people are visiting them from and may use that data for analytics, logging, or optimized caching, for example.

Let's say you are on a site say google, and you clicked on the link of your site:

This is what you will receive in **Request Headers**

```
**Referer**: https://www.google.com/
```

And if you click on `https://www.apple.com` from google, and apple sites redirect you to let say `https://www.apple.com/lae/` then on Request header's Referer you will receive:

```
**Referer**: https://www.apple.com
```

or, you can also receive `google.com` and others, it depends

> NOTE: **The HTTP referer header can be spoofed** So it's not fixed what you received!